# Fetching source file names of include files dynamically: ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

What are some alternate approaches of determining the filename(s) of source file(s) included in another source file dynamically? I'm trying to avoid hard-coding file names where possible.

I'm currently using a workaround discussed in this [page](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/files/directories-fso/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-url/page.html)

I'm just wondering though if there are better ways than that suggested approach.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for an ASP file to know what file it is #include'ing is for it to read itself in as a text file, and parse itself looking for "#include" strings.

The *very* first thing the ASP interpreter does when a script runs is to go through and glue  all of the `#include`'d code in to the parent file's code [in memory].  By the time the actual code is interpreted, it isn't even aware that it's split across more than one file.

`Server.Execute()` is probably what you're after... you can define what files to execute on the fly. They don't even necessarily have to exist before the script runs (although that's not really a recommended practice ;-))

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_execute.asp